# MongoDB: errors while inserting document using mongoimport

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to insert a huge(~831M) file into mongo collection using mongoimport

```
/Library/mongodb/bin/mongoimport --port 12345 -d staging -c collection < out.all.1
```

and see some errors like

```
exception:Failure parsing JSON string near: , 'Custome
```

and there are instances where I found some weird characters

```
'CustomerCity': u'Wall \xa0'
'CustomerCity': u'La Ca\xc3\xb1ada Flintridge'
'CustomerCity': u'La Ca\xf1ada Flintridge'
```

How do I resolve these issues?

Thank you

Comment: A few questions: what version of mongo are you using to do the import? what version captured the data? what driver (type and version)? Any frameworks e.g. mongoose, mongoid?

Comment: I am using mongodb shell, version 1.8.1, data is computed via python program and inserted using mongoimport, file structure is JSON based document

Answer (score 0):

I struck a similar problem where mongoimport gave errors about non-UTF8 characters in a flat file I'd asked it to import. This [google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/b7oTglb8GnI) led me to try putting my source data file through iconv on the unix command line to 'correct' non-UTF-8 characters, thus:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

That solved the issue for me. I wonder if that approach might help you? While the error you're seeing is different, it's the odd characters that are messing up the JSON parsing, no?

One wonders, however, how those odd characters are ending up in your output data if you're generating it yourself. Perhaps you could filter in the code that generates the output?